# Python Code in the terminal instead of Output VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, output

So I'm new to programming and have used PyCharm. I have gotten Mosh Hamedani's course and saw that whatever code he executes is shown in its output window NEATLY. My code is jumbled up with stupid commands which are telling me the location of the file etc. How can I make ONLY MY EXECUTED CODE show up in the output or terminal? I just want to get rid of those Windows PowerShell etc stuff. The highlighted part is the code I ran and want only that to be shown and nothing else??

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please give preference to text rather than image. Please check here on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the powershell copyright banner using `-NoLogo`

Start your terminal with command :

```
Powershell.exe -NoLogo
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-nologo).